# Make a (deep) copy of an Object that conforms to Codable

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable

I have an object that subclasses `Object` from Realm, and conforms to `Codable` in order to convert to and from JSON when talking to an API.

How can I make a deep copy (include children objects) by leveraging the `Codable` protocol?

Comment: Why do you need to use `Codable`? Is `NSCopying` insufficient? This is going to be really high overhead for an operation that can be performed (relatively) cheaply in comparison...

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention that my object subclasses 'Object' from Realm, and has a List<> property. I will update the question.

Answer (score 6):

This will make a deep copy of an object leveraging the `Codable` protocol. As mentioned by @itai-ferber it will have a high overhead when compared to `NSCopying`.

```
class MyObject: Object, Codable {

    /* details omitted */
    var children = List<ChildObject>()

    func copy() throws -> MyObject {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        let copy = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: data)
        return copy
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This implementation is a bit more generic,

```
extension Encodable where Self: Decodable {
    func copy() throws -> Self {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```