# Create instance from class using other class instance

Tags: swift, design-patterns, adapter

So i came across this case, an already published application needed to change all of it's **API's & Models**.

---

Now i have created a generic tier to handle the requests and apis and almost mid way into implementing all the services, now i came across this problem, the previous defined models are used widely around the application of course and since its `MVC` , **Massive View Controller**. it is going to cost me too much changing everything in each scene to the new model type,
 therefore i thought of making an adapter to cast the new models when i get them in my 
 callback closure  to the old ones type.

---

I have already figured out a way but the problem its pretty much long, long way i am looking for a better approach if existed and a better solution over all for the case if there was a better one.

---

```
protocol Parsable {
    var time: String { get }
    var span: String { get }
    init(_ copy: Parsable)
}

class Foo: Parsable {
    required init(_ copy: Parsable) {
        self.span =  copy.span
        self.time =  copy.time
    }

    init(time: String, span: String) {
        self.time = time
        self.span = span
    }
    var time = ""
    var span = ""
}

class Fee: Parsable {
    required init(_ copy: Parsable) {
        self.span =  copy.span
        self.time = copy.time
    }
    init(time: String, span: String, date: String) {
        self.time = time
        self.span = span
        self.date = date // an extra var that is not used in Foo
    }
    var time = ""
    var span = ""
    var date = ""
}

var foo = Foo(time: "", span: "")
var fee = Fee(time: "2", span: "ye", date: "123")
// Usage
var deeped = Foo(fee)
```

---

As you can tell from the code i've created a `protocol` that contains the variables and an `init()` that holds its type, now imagine this to implement a model with **+50** variable and **+40** model in total, might need an age or two.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't be declaring everything as mutable and you also shouldn't be assigning dummy default values to variables that get a proper value in the initialiser. Some general Swift advice: only declare a variable as mutable if you absolutely need to mutate if after initialisation. Only use default values if they are meaningful or if you cannot get away without using one. Only use a `class` instead of a `struct` if you need reference-type behaviour.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the advise, and yeah i usually use struct in modeling but i am in this deep code and i tried to simulate exactly what's in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Achieved this using `Codable`, i have created a dummy protocol that is conforming to `Codable`, and using that in every `class`, `struct` that i needed to convert it, and created a generic function extended from that protocol, to encode the object to data then decode it into the new type desired,

With that i don't have to declare any variable or property i needed to copy manually.

check out the code below.

```
protocol Convertable: Codable {}

class Foo: Convertable {
    var foo: String
    var fee: String
    init(foo: String, fee: String) {
        self.foo = foo
        self.fee = fee
    }
}
class Fee: Convertable{
    var fee: String
     init( fee: String) {
        self.fee = fee
    }
}

//Generic function to convert
extension Convertable {
    func convert<T: Codable>(_ primary: T.Type) -> T? {
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(primary, from: try! JSONEncoder().encode(self))
    }
}
var foo = Foo(foo: "nothing", fee: "nothing")
let fee = foo.convert(Fee.self)
fee?.fee // nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood the problem, It's not a clean solution but it's quick an flexible:

What about an additional method in the protocol with an implementation in it's extension to perform the all the copies? This is possible since i see that all the properties have an assigned dummy value. Then the only thing to do for each object implementing Parsable is to call such method in the initializer. kind of a `commonInit()` method.

```
protocol Parsable {
    var time: String { get }
    var span: String { get }
    init(_ copy: Parsable)
    func initParsableProperties(from copy: Parsable)
}

extension Parsable {
    func initParsableProperties(from copy: Parsable) {
        self.span =  copy.span
        self.time = copy.time
    }
}

class Foo: Parsable {
    ...
    required init(_ copy: Parsable) {
        initParsableProperties(from: copy)
    }
    ...

}
```

This also allows you to add additional properties in the initializers if needded. If you don't need additional properties it could then be directly implemented in the initializer, but it requires some more tricky solutions.

Comment: Yeah but i still come thru the declaring everything manually ... is there anything that could cast this automatically :/

Comment: Well, it's only once, but if you want to automate that as well, maybe you want to check if possible with Codable protocol (or any serialization method/lib like ObjectMapper) and some workarunds like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900984/make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-that-conforms-to-codable
Basically you serialize the first object and deserialize it to the new one. but it's neither compile time safe, nor performant, but i think it's doable.